# How to delete draft message using gamil api?

Tags: gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

I am using API 
 var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.drafts.delete({
    'userId': userId,
    'id': draftId
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) { });

always getting error 
 "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `draftId` of the draft, and not its regular message `id`?

Comment: I am getting draft list by label "DRAFT" in which It has some id , I am not sure It has draftId or regularId

Comment: Alright. Have you tried listing the drafts directly instead of listing messages with the draft label? If you try the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list) for listing drafts you will see that each draft has two ids; a draft id and a message id.

Comment: Alright, I will try thanks for you answer